# Best running time to order n numbers

Tags: sorting, asymptotic-complexity, radix-sort

I have n numbers between 0 and (n^4 - 1) what is the fastest way I can sort them.

Of course, nlogn is trivial, but I thought about the option of Radix Sort with base n and than it will be linear time, but I am not sure because of the -1.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the efficiency of Radix Sort. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Efficiency):

> Radix sort complexity is O(wn) for n keys which are integers of word size w. Sometimes w is presented as a constant, which would make radix sort better (for sufficiently large n) than the best comparison-based sorting algorithms, which all perform O(n log n) comparisons to sort n keys. However, in general w cannot be considered a constant: if all n keys are distinct, then w has to be at least log n for a random-access machine to be able to store them in memory, which gives at best a time complexity O(n log n).

I personally would implement quicksort choosing an [intelligent pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot). Using this method you can achieve about `1.188 n log n` efficiency.

Comment: If it was n^4 we could represent the numbers in base n and achieve O(4n) hence O(n) time, but the -1 is my problem...

Comment: I see your problem now. I'll ask my algorithms professor after class tomorrow and see what he says.

Answer (score 0):

If we use Radix Sort in base n we get the desired linear time complexity, the -1 doesn't matter.

We will represent the numbers in base n:

Then we get : <= (log(base n) of (n^4 - 1)) * (n + n) <= 4 * (2n) <= O(n).

n is for n numbers, the other n is just the digits span (overestimate) and log of n^4 - 1 is less than log n^4 which is 4 in base n. Overall linear time complexity.

Thanks for the help anyway! If I did something wrong please notify me!